# How do I use the double click signal in the QLineEdit widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have a QLineEdit widget and I want to use the double click event on it. How can I do that?

```py
def __init__(self):
    #... other codes

    self.title = QLineEdit()
    self.title.returnPressed.connect(self.lockTitle)

    #like this -> 'self.title.doubleClicked.connect(self.unlockTitle)'

    #... other codes 
def lockTitle(self):
    self.title.setDisabled(True)

def unlockTitle(self):
    self.title.setDisabled(False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a custom `QLineEdit` by creating a new signal that is emitted in the `mouseDoubleClickEvent` method, but the problem in your case is that the QLineEdit is disabled and that method is not invoked so instead of using that method you should use the `event` method:

```py
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    doubleClicked = pyqtSignal()

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonDblClick:
            self.doubleClicked.emit()
        return super().event(event)
```

```
self.title = LineEdit()
self.title.returnPressed.connect(self.lockTitle)
self.title.doubleClicked.connect(self.unlockTitle)
```